# Node-RED: post data API but No response

Tags: node-red

I have flow join `token` and `stationCodesArrayto` by 2 function have same all just different are function 18 I use data from variable but part function 19 I use data

**function 18** by post

```
msg.payload = {
    "devIds": stationCodesArray,
    "devTypeId": "1"
};
```

but result

```
{"failCode":305,"immediately":true,"message":"USER_MUST_RELOGIN"}
```

next I use `stationCodesArrayto` to post in **function19**

```
msg.payload = {
    "devIds": "1000000033796206,1000000033796207,1000000033817103,1000000033817104,1000000033827159,1000000033827160,1000000033827161,1000000033862908,1000000033862909,1000000033862910,1000000033862911,1000000033867628,1000000033868090,1000000033868436,1000000033871558,1000000033876891,1000000033877310,1000000033877311,1000000033877312,1000000033877313,1000000033919425,1000000033919670,1000000033919701,1000000033920765,1000000033920766,1000000033920767,1000000033958299,1000000033958300,1000000033967998,1000000033967999,1000000033968024,1000000033968025,1000000033968101,1000000033968102,1000000033968152,1000000033968153,1000000033968154,1000000033968234,1000000033968235,1000000033968236,1000000033968237,1000000033968238,1000000033968264,1000000033968265,1000000033968266,1000000033968267,1000000033968268,1000000033968269,1000000034021375,1000000034021376,1000000034021377,1000000034021378,1000000034021379,1000000034021380,1000000034021381,1000000034021382",
    "devTypeId": "1"
};
```

result is work

```
"failCode": 0 "success": true
```

my Node-RED are

[image: Node-RED flow]

```
[
{
    "id": "c79b33c20928959b",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Token In",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "token",
    "payloadType": "flow",
    "x": 520,
    "y": 1160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "594fe2cdd5bcc73f"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "5f980ab37ff5564b",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Inverter In",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "inverter",
    "payloadType": "flow",
    "x": 520,
    "y": 1120,
    "wires": [
        [
            "594fe2cdd5bcc73f",
            "95fa3f64d0331c27"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "82856b1b6b0dba97",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "function 18",
    "func": "msg.headers = {};\nmsg.url = \"https://sg5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/thirdData/getDevRealKpi\";\nmsg.headers[\"content-type\"] = \"application/json\";\nlet token = Object.values(msg.payload)[1];\nmsg.headers[\"XSRF-TOKEN\"] = token;\n\n\n// Extract the station codes from the payload\nlet stationCodesArray = Object.values(msg.payload)[0];\n\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"devIds\": stationCodesArray,\n    \"devTypeId\": \"1\"\n};\n\nnode.log(msg.payload);\nreturn msg;\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 870,
    "y": 1140,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "594fe2cdd5bcc73f",
    "type": "join",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "",
    "mode": "custom",
    "build": "object",
    "property": "payload",
    "propertyType": "msg",
    "key": "payload",
    "joiner": "\\n",
    "joinerType": "str",
    "accumulate": false,
    "timeout": "",
    "count": "2",
    "reduceRight": false,
    "reduceExp": "",
    "reduceInit": "",
    "reduceInitType": "num",
    "reduceFixup": "",
    "x": 710,
    "y": 1140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "25634cc1b5cf2cf5",
            "bac6f58d38039cd9",
            "642dc259cd5d1dbc",
            "5d58310b7ef765f9"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "b559e0343ab2bf59",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Output Inverter",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 1300,
    "y": 1140,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "25634cc1b5cf2cf5",
    "type": "http request",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "[Inverter]",
    "method": "POST",
    "ret": "obj",
    "paytoqs": "ignore",
    "url": "https://sg5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/thirdData/getDevRealKpi",
    "tls": "",
    "persist": false,
    "proxy": "",
    "insecureHTTPParser": false,
    "authType": "",
    "senderr": false,
    "headers": [],
    "x": 1060,
    "y": 1140,
    "wires": [
        [
            "b559e0343ab2bf59"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "66d5571fcc22f266",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "debug 28",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 1240,
    "y": 1000,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "bac6f58d38039cd9",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Check Token",
    "func": "// Extract the station codes from the payload\nlet token = Object.values(msg.payload)[1];\n\nmsg.payload = token\nreturn msg;\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 1070,
    "y": 1200,
    "wires": [
        [
            "cf001141eab36bcd"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "cf001141eab36bcd",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Token",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 1250,
    "y": 1200,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "642dc259cd5d1dbc",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Check Station",
    "func": "// Extract the station codes from the payload\nlet stationCodesArray = Object.values(msg.payload)[0];\n\nmsg.payload = stationCodesArray\nreturn msg;\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 1080,
    "y": 1280,
    "wires": [
        [
            "60517cfeb49d93e1"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "60517cfeb49d93e1",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "Station",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 1260,
    "y": 1280,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "5d58310b7ef765f9",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "function 19",
    "func": "msg.headers = {};\nmsg.url = \"https://sg5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/thirdData/getDevRealKpi\";\nmsg.headers[\"content-type\"] = \"application/json\";\nlet token = Object.values(msg.payload)[1];\nmsg.headers[\"XSRF-TOKEN\"] = token;\n\n\n// Extract the station codes from the payload\n// let stationCodesArray = Object.values(msg.payload)[0];\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"devIds\": \"1000000033796206,1000000033796207,1000000033817103,1000000033817104,1000000033827159,1000000033827160,1000000033827161,1000000033862908,1000000033862909,1000000033862910,1000000033862911,1000000033867628,1000000033868090,1000000033868436,1000000033871558,1000000033876891,1000000033877310,1000000033877311,1000000033877312,1000000033877313,1000000033919425,1000000033919670,1000000033919701,1000000033920765,1000000033920766,1000000033920767,1000000033958299,1000000033958300,1000000033967998,1000000033967999,1000000033968024,1000000033968025,1000000033968101,1000000033968102,1000000033968152,1000000033968153,1000000033968154,1000000033968234,1000000033968235,1000000033968236,1000000033968237,1000000033968238,1000000033968264,1000000033968265,1000000033968266,1000000033968267,1000000033968268,1000000033968269,1000000034021375,1000000034021376,1000000034021377,1000000034021378,1000000034021379,1000000034021380,1000000034021381,1000000034021382\",\n    \"devTypeId\": \"1\"\n};\n\nnode.log(msg.payload);\nreturn msg;\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 890,
    "y": 1040,
    "wires": [
        [
            "356e5dbfb75fa741"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "356e5dbfb75fa741",
    "type": "http request",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "[Inverter]",
    "method": "POST",
    "ret": "obj",
    "paytoqs": "ignore",
    "url": "https://sg5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/thirdData/getDevRealKpi",
    "tls": "",
    "persist": false,
    "proxy": "",
    "insecureHTTPParser": false,
    "authType": "",
    "senderr": false,
    "headers": [],
    "x": 1060,
    "y": 1040,
    "wires": [
        [
            "66d5571fcc22f266"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "95fa3f64d0331c27",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "86e67c863cb4f643",
    "name": "debug 30",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 680,
    "y": 1060,
    "wires": []
}
]
```

output picture are

[image: output picture]

Comment: Without knowing a more about the API you are trying to use I don't think anybody will be able to help here